# How do I do URL normalization in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rubygems, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a gem that does something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization.

Are there any open source projects that do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the addressable gem https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/

Comment: Do you know if there are any libraries for Semantic changing normalizations. This is great for changing 'http://wwW.nYtimes.com' to 'http://www.nytimes.com/'. I also want to deal with 'http://www.domain.com/index.html' when it's the same as 'http://www.domain.com/'.

Comment: I have code that does this in one of my apps, I but I wrote it myself using a combination of string functions and regex. Not aware of anything out of the box...

Answer (score 3):

Check out [URI.normalize](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/URI/Generic.html#M001725).